# upload file and give download link in telerik Rad-Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

Here is my code of Rad-editor ,

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1Content" runat="server" AutoResizeHeight="True"
Width="500px" ToolbarMode="Floating">
<Content>
</Content>
<ImageManager EnableAsyncUpload="True" ViewPaths="~/images" UploadPaths="~/images" MaxUploadFileSize="900000000"/>
<MediaManager EnableAsyncUpload="true" ViewPaths="~/media" UploadPaths="~/media"  MaxUploadFileSize="900000000"/>
<TrackChangesSettings CanAcceptTrackChanges="False"></TrackChangesSettings>
```

Uploading works correctly in my Rad-Editor , but when I insert uploaded file , rad-editor shows likes

```
<object height="150" width="150" type="application/x-oleobject" 
classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="URL" value="/media/MySongFile.mp3"><embed src="/media/MySongFile.mp3"
 type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer" width="150" height="150">
```

It shows my uploaded file(mp3) with MediaPlayer which can be play . I don't want to show likes this .
I just want to show `Download Link` to download my uploaded file . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnClientPasteHtml event to modify the pasted content: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-onclientpastehtml.html
For example, to add some text after an image:

```
function OnClientPasteHtml(sender, args)
        {
            if (args.get_commandName() == "ImageManager")
            {
                args.set_value(args.get_value() + " my modification");
            }
        }
```

And in a similar fashion you can get the desired manager (Flash, Document, etc.), extract the src and generate an anchor.